# No wifi option in ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: wireless

In ubuntu 20.04lts it is showing me no wifi adapter found. I am new to linux and I don't know how to fix it so it would be very helpful if someone could provide me with step by step guide to enable wifi.Below is the terminal output:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0621]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the output of the commands `lspci` and `lsusb`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: The driver is installed. Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and it will work.

Comment: i am new to linux so can you please tell me how to disable secure boot in BIOS?

Comment: It is not related to linux. Enter your BIOS settings and disable Secure Boot there.

Comment: thank you @Pilot6 my problem got solved after disabling secure boot in BIOS.

Comment: @VivekFalkar Can you please provide the step how to disabling the secure boot in BIOS